# Parsing InputStream from URL with parameters

Tags: java, android, parsing, inputstream, jdom

I'm trying to parse next url:
http://kavim-t.co.il/include/getXMLStations.asp?parent=55_%20_2

Code:

```
//using jdom SAX parser
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
URL url = new URL("http://kavim-t.co.il/include/getXMLStations.asp?parent=55_%20_2");
InputStream in = getInputStrem(url);
Document document = builder.build(in); ...
```

getInputStream():

```
public static InputStream getInputStrem(URL url) {
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.connect();
        in = con.getInputStream();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return in;
}
```

Exception "Error on line 3: At line 3, column 29: not well-formed (invalid token)"

is getting when trying to run next line:

```
Document document = builder.build(in)
```

I think the problem is in the getInputStream() function,

because if I replace Url to simpler one (with no parameters and classic structure) , it's working fine.

Comment: It seems you are receiving any data in stream. Did you type same url in any browser and see data?

Comment: Yes. if I type next url : http://kavim-t.co.il/include/getXMLStations.asp?parent=55_%20_2 in Chrome I can see the data.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a character-encoding problem. The error you are getting is probably because the InputStream is being interpreted in a different charset to the actual data.

URL's have an input stream, but also a charset. You are ignoring that charset when you supply the stream to JDOM.

The first thing you should try is to remove all your getInputStream code. JDOM has a straight SAXBuilder.build(URL) method, and that method will take both the stream and charset in to consideration...

Your entire code could be simplified that way. In fact, if you give JDOM a strin argument, it interprets it as a URL (SystemID), so your code could be as simple as:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document document = builder.build("http://kavim-t.co.il/include/getXMLStations.asp?parent=55_%20_2");
```

EDIT: ---

Well, I ran 'my' version of the code though in my environment, and (using Xerces as a parser) I got more detail on the problem....:

```
Caused by: org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanContent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanContent(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
```

So, it would seem that your input data is not encoded correctly....

EDIT AGAIN:

Here is the output of xmllint on the input document. xmllint is a unix program available on most Linux distributions. It provides a good 'objective' way to validate your XML.

```
david.xml:3: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xEE 0xF1 0xE5 0xF3
<option value="22958">22958: Ã®Ã±Ã¥Ã³ Ã¸Ã©Ã£Ã©Ã°Ã¢</option><option value="22920">22920: Ã£Ã©
                             ^
```

Really, you have a broken XML document. If you *insist* though, you can add an error-handler to JDOM's SAXBuilder that ignores the error. See the documentation for JDOM here: http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/input/SAXBuilder.html#setErrorHandler%28org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler%29 where you can add an ErrorHandler that ignores the problem. (override the error method, and return instead of throwing the exception)..... then the problem will not be reported, and the parser will 'continue', but you *will* be missing data in your parsed results....

Comment: Thanks for answering! so what can I do to parse this data? there must be a way to do that...

Comment: Just edited my answer to add detail on the xmllint and on the ErrorHandler for SAXBuilder

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue reading from a file, I solved with this:

```
File file = new File("/somewhere/somefile.xml"); 
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();           
Document doc = builder.build(reader);
```

In your case you probably would obtain the stream from URL like:

```
InputStream stream = new URL("http://www.somewhere.com/somefile.xml").openStream();
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();           
Document doc = builder.build(reader);
```

As a last resource (as the encoding cannot be enforced on Url::openStream()), I would save the data locally and then open it with a file stream like in my first example.

Comment: I forgot to say credits go to: http://hackingthenet.wordpress.com/2008/02/25/jdom-and-special-characters/

Answer (score 0):

Your XML response text from the HTTP request is not well formed. Try validating it first. Hence, is the exception.

Comment: I'm new to all this Parsing issuse. So please, what do you mean by "validating it first"? In browser it's look fine.

Comment: @David So look harder. The SAX parser doesn't agree with you. Take a really good like at line 3 column 29.

Comment: Ok. but I have to understand if it's a Parser problem or a getInputStrem problem?

Comment: @David it is neither. It is a problem with the data.

Comment: It seems to be the case what @rolfl has mentioned above. I tried validating your data and seems fine. The data contains some hebrew characters and possibly the encoding issue is causing some IO exception while reading it. Please set the appropriately charset while reading the stream and try again.